# How can I persist a session specific value required in Application_AuthenticateRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a very large web application with many pages.  Those pages require us to know a user's role in order to correctly display content.  So in the Application_AuthenticationRequest, we have this code:

```
 var id = new GenericIdentity(Request.Headers["ceid"]);
 var rp = new MyRoleProvider();
 var principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, rp.GetRolesForUser(id.Name));
 Context.User = principal;
```

The problem is that we need to use a web service to get the roles, and because that call is being made every time every user visits a page, the web service is being hit too many times.

The ideal solution would be if we could store the roles in a session variable, however, session is not available in Application_AuthenticateRequest.  We considered storing a dictionary with entries for all user in an application variable but I'm hoping we can find a better solution.

Is there any way we can store the current user's roles in such a way that they will be available inside Application_AuthenticationRequest?  We are very security consciousness; would a cookie be a valid option?

Comment: Are you aware that there is out-of-the-box functionality to 'cache' a user's roles in a cookie? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.cacherolesincookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That works if you want to use the Roles API; a lot of people role their own so storing in a cookie that has HttpOnly (only available on the server) set to true is a good solution.

Comment: If you don't like to use a cookie maybe [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a static class to hold our list of roles for all current users (basically extending on your Dictionary idea): if roles for a given ID aren't present in the list, we retrieve them from the web service. Otherwise we return the stored roles. 

We need the means to expire data after a certain amount of user inactivity (we don't wanna keep all roles for all users in memory at all times) so we'll implement our own expiration mechanism (20 minutes in my example).

Here's how I would write the class, and how I would use it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the static class that will hold the roles for all active users (active users 
    /// are those that have been using the website within the last 20 minutes).
    /// </summary>
    public static class MyRoles
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This class holds your roles
        /// </summary>
        private class Principal
        {
            private DateTime lastAccess; // Our expiration timer
            private System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal principal; // Our roles

            public Principal(System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal principal)
            {
                this.principal = principal;
                this.lastAccess = DateTime.Now;
            }

            public System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal GenericPrincipal
            {
                get
                { 
                    // We reset our timer. It will expire 20 minutes from now. 
                    this.lastAccess = DateTime.Now;

                    return principal;
                }
            }                                

            /// <summary>
            /// This tells us if a user has been active in the last 20 minutes
            /// </summary>
            public bool IsValid
            {
                get
                {
                    // Valid within 20 minutes from last call
                    return DateTime.Now <= this.lastAccess.AddMinutes(20);                        
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This will hold IDs and related roles
        /// </summary>
        private static Dictionary<string, Principal> ids = new Dictionary<string, Principal>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to retrieve roles for a given ID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="header">Our ID</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal GetRoles(string header)
        {
            if (ids.ContainsKey(header) && ids[header].IsValid)
            {
                // We have roles for this ID
                return ids[header].GenericPrincipal;
            }
            else
            {
                // We don't have this ID (or it's expired) so get it from the web service
                var id = new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(header);
                var principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, new MyRoleProvider().GetRolesForUser(id.Name));

                // Store roles
                ids.Add(header, new Principal(principal));

                return principal;
            }
        }            
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is how we use our class
        var principal = MyRoles.GetRoles(Request.Headers["ceid"]);
    }
```

Please note that my sample code doesn't take into account the memory footprint required to store a list of GenericPrincipal instances. My goal is solely to give you an idea on how to persist (and expire) user data without using the Session object. 


The 20 minutes expiration mechanism can be easily linked to the Session_End event so that it will expire data as soon as a session is over (if you're using InProc sessions).


Please also note that, just like sessions, this solution only works for single server environments. If you have a load-balanced environment (2 or more web servers), you'd have to persist your data to a DB.


I hope this helps you out. If it doesn't, please let me know why and I will try my best to help you out :)

Comment: Thanks, @Alex...I will try this out as soon as I can.  Sorry for the delay but my trial version of VS2013 just expired and I work for a large company, so getting them to give me an actual MSDN license is taking longer than might be hoped :(

Comment: No problem, @FrancineDeGroodTaylor. Just remember to keep an eye on the memory footprint of that static class (just like you would when using the Session object). If you need me, you know where to find me :)